Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not load file '/public/content-script.bundle.js'. It isn't UTF-8 encoded. Using chrome.scripting.executeScript
Goal
I am trying to create a Chrome extension that will embed a CodeMirror Editor in the web page. I use vite for bundling the CodeMirror package and use chrome.scripting.executeScript to run my javascript file.
Setup
manifest.json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Odoo Better Ide",
    "description": "Better Ide",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/icon-16.png",
        "32": "images/icon-32.png",
        "48": "images/icon-48.png",
        "128": "images/icon-128.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "src/background.js",
        "type": "module"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "images/icon-16.png",
            "32": "images/icon-32.png",
            "48": "images/icon-48.png",
            "128": "images/icon-128.png"
        }
    },
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"]
}

background.js (for my service worker and check if the user clicks the extension icon)
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    chrome.action.setBadgeText({
        text: "OFF",
    });
});

const odooUrl = "https://demo";
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async (tab) => {
    if (tab.url.startsWith(odooUrl)) {
        const prevState = await chrome.action.getBadgeText({ tabId: tab.id });
        const nextState = prevState === "ON" ? "OFF" : "ON";

        await chrome.action.setBadgeText({
            tabId: tab.id,
            text: nextState,
        });

        if (nextState === "ON") {
            chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: { tabId: tab.id },
                files: ["/dist/content-script.bundle.js"], // this is the bundled js file
            });
        } else if (nextState === "OFF") {
            console.log("Turned off");
        }
    }
});

content-script.js (will be bundled by vite rollup)
import { EditorView, basicSetup } from "codemirror";
import { python } from "@codemirror/lang-python";

const ideElem = document.querySelector(".o_field_code");
console.log(ideElem);

if (ideElem) {
    console.log(ideElem);
    const editorElem = initiazeEditorView(ideElem);
    console.log(editorElem);
}

function initiazeEditorView(ideElem) {
    let editor = new EditorView({
        extensions: [basicSetup, python()],
        parent: ideElem,
    });
    return editor;
}

vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { nodeResolve } from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import terser from "@rollup/plugin-terser";

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            input: "src/content-script.js",
            output: {
                dir: "dist",
                entryFileNames: "content-script.bundle.js",
                format: "iife",
            },
            plugins: [nodeResolve(), terser()],
        },
    },
});

Problem/Issue
The extension is working properly but everytime I tried to run (click the extension icon) and execute the code:
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    files: ["/dist/content-script.bundle.js"], // this is the bundled js file
});

It always shows me an error Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not load file '/dist/content-script.bundle.js'. It isn't UTF-8 encoded.
When I opened the bundled file in VSCode it shows that it's a "UTF-8". I also tried the Save with encoding feature of VSCode but still no luck.
If you want to clone the repo here's the link: https://github.com/dwarjie/odoo-better-ide

Remove /dist in executeScript because the root of your extension is where manifest.json is.

@woxxom I already tried moving the bundled file (content-script.bundle.js) in the root folder and removed the “/dist” in the executeScript. But it still shows the same error.

I mean the root folder is where your installed extension's manifest.json is i.e. dist is your root folder.

It returns an error of Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not load file: 'content-script.bundle.js'.

Open your dist folder, make sure the file is there, use "/content-script.bundle.js" in executeScript.

Check the file with a hex editor.  Allowable UTF-chars are:
0xxxxxxx
or
110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
or
1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
or
11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx

--For example, 0xF8 = 11111000 is not allowed.
Also, you might need to include the BOM char (Byte Order Mark) = 0x EF BB BF, which is a marker to indicate the byte ordering which is either little endian (most significant byte stored in the larger memory address), or big endian (most significant byte stored in the smaller memory address), especially if the file needs to be explicitly recognized as UTF-8 by older systems.
But the BOM might need to be omitted for interoperability with unix/linux environments.
